# how to set depth mode for ASUS xTion Pro Live

Tags: ros, openni, asus-xtion-pro-live

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone.
I'm trying to set  the depth video mode on an ASUS xTion Pro Live.
As suggested in the code API, I'm setting the video mode this way:

```
depthMode_ = depthStream_.getSensorInfo().getSupportedVideoModes()[4];
  ROS_INFO("The wished depth mode is %d x %d at %d FPS. Pixel format %d", depthMode_.getResolutionX(),
           depthMode_.getResolutionY(), depthMode_.getFps(), depthMode_.getPixelFormat());
  if (depthStream_.setVideoMode(depthMode_) != openni::STATUS_OK)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Can't apply depth-videomode");
    depthMode_ = depthStream_.getVideoMode();
    ROS_INFO("The depth mode is set to %d x %d at %d FPS. Pixel format %d", depthMode_.getResolutionX(),
             depthMode_.getResolutionY(), depthMode_.getFps(), depthMode_.getPixelFormat());
  }
```

unfortunately, even if the mode (RES=640x420, FPS=30 PF=100) is supported, this operation fails.

The full node can be found [here](https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker/blob/master/include/skeleton_tracker/xtion_tracker.hpp)

Did anyone manage to set the resolution for the depth mode?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212743/how-to-set-depth-mode-for-asus-xtion-pro-live/) by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved!
I moved the skeleton tracker initializer:

```
niteRc_ = userTracker_.create();
if (niteRc_ != nite::STATUS_OK)
{
  ROS_FATAL("Couldn't create user tracker");
  ros::shutdown();
  return;
}
```

after setting the RGB and the DEPTH modes.
If you are interested, the code is available [here](https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker). The node is an extension for the openni2_tracker. The node tracks the skeleton and publishes rgb stream, depth stream and point cloud. Furthermore the node publishes a topic with the IDs of the tracked users.

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0